# findInterval() in R behaves unexpectedly

Tags: r, intervals

I think I found a weird behavior in R's function `base::findInterval()`.

I have a long vector `p` of cumulative values in the range (0,1]. For the sake of simplicity, we could define `p` as

```r
ones <- rep(1, 2000)
p <- cumsum(ones)/sum(ones)
head(p)
#> [1] 0.0005 0.0010 0.0015 0.0020 0.0025 0.0030
tail(p)
#> [1] 0.9975 0.9980 0.9985 0.9990 0.9995 1.0000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Problem

I need to find the indexes of `p` of those values for which the interval changes based on vector `probs` of breakpoints: `probs  <- seq(1/nbins,1, 1/nbins)`, where `nbins` (100, in my case) is the number of breaks.

I am using `findInterval()` for this task and I found that for some sections of `p` it correctly identifies the intervals, but for others, it does not.

### Example

In the example below, I created vectors, `x`, `y`, and `z`, which are subsets of `p` but are sufficient to show the problem. Notice that `findInterval()` works great with `x` and `y`, but it misidentifies the interval in `z`. Does any of you know why? Am I doing something wrong?

```r
# Number of bins
nbins <- 100

# Cuts in the cumulative distribution
probs  <- seq(1/nbins,1, 1/nbins)

# subsets of the large cumulative distribution
x <- c(0.0095, 0.01, 0.0105, 0.011)
y <- c(0.0495, 0.05, 0.0505, 0.051)
z <- c(0.0595, 0.06, 0.0605, 0.061)

# These two work fine
findInterval(x,probs)
#> [1] 0 1 1 1
findInterval(y,probs)
#> [1] 4 5 5 5

# this should be c(5, 6, 6, 6) NOT c(5, 5, 6, 6)
findInterval(z,probs)
#> [1] 5 5 6 6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Implication

Notice that in this example, `p` is a straightforward vector and we know the actual indexes beforehand. But in a real case scenario, we won't know if `findInterval()` is working correctly.

### side note

As a side note, I am identifying the indexes with the code below. I think it should be working fine if `findInterval()` works correctly. Do you know if there is any other, super-efficient way to find the indexes?

```r
# these are the indexes
ind <-
   findInterval(p, probs) |>
    diff() |> {
    \(.) which(. == 1)
     }() + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an example of the [floating point problem](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) in R.  Below you can see that even though `probs[6]` prints as `0.06` it is not equivalent to that number:

```r
nbins <- 100

# Cuts in the cumulative distribution
probs  <- seq(1/nbins,1, 1/nbins)

probs[6]
#> [1] 0.06
probs[6] == .06
#> [1] FALSE
```

If you round the probabilities in `probs` even to 15 decimal places, you get the expected result.

```r
# subsets of the large cumulative distribution
x <- c(0.0095, 0.01, 0.0105, 0.011)
y <- c(0.0495, 0.05, 0.0505, 0.051)
z <- c(0.0595, 0.06, 0.0605, 0.061)

findInterval(z, probs)
#> [1] 5 5 6 6
findInterval(z, round(probs, 15))
#> [1] 5 6 6 6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. But, how do we know that rounding to the 15th decimal point is enough? It may vary depending on how the `probs` vector was created, right?

Comment: In the superseding post linked by @MrFlick, it suggests that `.Machine$double.eps` is the smallest positive value (`x`), such that `1 + x != 1`. This is `2.220446e-16` in R, which is 0 in the first 15 decimal places.  So, it should be that rounding to 15 decimal places would work.  Happy to be corrected if I'm thinking about this the wrong way, though.